# How does 'track by' work in ngOptions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select:

```
<select id="provinceId" name="provinceId" ng-model="provinces.selected" ng-required ng-change="getAreas()"
        ng-options="item.label for item in provinces track by item.id" class="form-control"></select>
```

Given some stuff I've read, I got the distinct impression that the `track by item.id` would cause the `ng-model="provinces.selected"` to set `provinces.selected` to the `id` of the selected province, where it actually sets it to the whole province object. Where is the tidy separation of selected Id, and selected Item we normally have in non-angular dropdowns?

Comment: I suggest to read the documentation instead of "some stuff". `item.id as item.label for item`.

Comment: That stuff included the documentation, but I was scanning a lot of help and docs on the subject in a very short time.

Answer (score 0):

To set the **id** to **provinces.selected** model you should do as

```
<select id="provinceId" name="provinceId" ng-model="provinces.selected" ng-required ng-change="getAreas()"
    ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in provinces track by item.id" class="form-control"></select>
```

For information about *track by* you can read [this angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)....Good Luck